# Refresh Partial View and build a query string without refreshing all page in Asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, get

I want to refresh only the partial view, but in the same time I want to build a url address in search bar, to make it easier for users to share their search results. I made layout with filtering area and result area as a partial view. Is posible to make it as I would like or is another way to do this in asp.net mvc 5?

1. Layout with filtering area

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    // filtering area
  </div>
  <div class="col-6" id="divPartial">
    @Html.Partial("ItemsPartial")
  </div>
</div>
```

2. when user click some parametrs in filtering area is called this function:

```
$('#divPartial').load('/Szukaj/ItemsPartial?rodzajSamochodu='+rodzaj);
```

3. ItemsPartial:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  // do some stuff
}
```

4. ItemsPartial ActionLink

```
public ActionResult ItemsPartial(FiltrModel results)
{
  // filtering logic using data from "FiltrModel"
  return PartialView("ItemsPartial", model);
}
```

Comment: Are you actually wanting to refresh the partial view or are you wanting to do it refresh without the user noticing?

Comment: Those parameters won't show up in the browser's address bar, since they are used internally in JavaScript only. You'd need to do a whole page refresh, or use a fragment identifier, to pull off what you are talking about.